# PHP shell_exec not running with my own applications only on Windows (8)

Tags: php, windows, shell-exec

We are trying to run some C applications from PHP, for example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

This application is copied the same directory the PHP script is located and run like this:

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec(FULLPATHTO . 'HelloWorld.exe');
  echo $output;
?>
```

When run on Linux everything runs fine, the application just needs to be owned by the correct usergroup and nothing needs to be configured on PHP.

On Windows the shell_exec command works fine:

- From the CLI with our application (running in php -a)
- Via script when using default Windows commands (shell_exec('dir'))
- Via script with some Windows applications (shell_exec(FULLPATHTO . 'notepad.exe') and shell_exec('notepad.exe'))

Also:

- A NodeJS app can run our application using spawn

Going further, when copying the "notepad.exe" executable to the folder containing the script it runs notepad correctly (from the given folder, not the notepad.exe on Windows folder) but doing EXACTLY the same with our application produces no output and the application is never opened.

- We already tried writing stderr output to a file but it's also blank.
- The user running Apache on Windows (SYSTEM) has full rights over the directory.
- PHP safe mode is not enabled.

Just to highlight some things again:

- The same code runs fine on Linux (same C code and same PHP code)
- The application is compiled correctly and can be run from outside PHP

Any guesses? Thanks!

Comment: Try exec() and check return_var. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php